# Basic question: degree of normal bundle is not self-intersection number

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, surfaces, vector-bundles, intersection-theory

For $C$ a (possibly singular) curve on a nonsingular projective surface $X$, let's define $C^2=deg_C(\mathcal{O}_X(C))$.

Why is it not the same as $deg_C(N_{X|C})$ when $C$ is singular?

Why do lecture notes always assume $X$ is nonsingular projective? What if it's only normal, or non-projective?

Where can I find an accessible discussion on these stuffs?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why did you define $C^2$ as $deg_C(O_C)$? Should it be $deg_C(O_X(C))$?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Of course I mean that! Thanks a lot for pointing it out!